# Text in matplotlib subplots in wrong positions

Tags: matplotlib, text, subplot

I'm trying to get some text into a matplotlib subplot, but I get it into weird locations.

The code I use is like the following:

```
limSX_list = [0, 0, 0]
limDX_list = [10, 10, 10]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
for xxx in range(3):
    for yyy in range(3):
        if xxx==yyy:
            #axs[xxx,yyy].hist( Deltas_list[xxx], range=[limSX_list[xxx], limDX_list[xxx]], bins=100, color='red' )
            axs[xxx,yyy].hist( Deltas_list[xxx], bins=100, color='red' )
        else:
            #axs[xxx,yyy].hist2d( Deltas_list[xxx], Deltas_list[yyy], bins=(100, 100), cmap=plt.cm.viridis, range=[[limSX_list[xxx],limDX_list[xxx]],[limSX_list[yyy],limDX_list[yyy]]], norm=LogNorm() )
            axs[xxx,yyy].hist2d( Deltas_list[xxx], Deltas_list[yyy], bins=(100, 100), cmap=plt.cm.viridis, norm=LogNorm() )

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        axs[row, col].text(0.5, 0.5, str((row, col)),color='blue', fontsize=18, ha='center')
        
plt.show()
```

And I get this weird output:
[image]

And if I set a x/y range (i.e. I uncomment the commented lines, and comment the ones below), I get the text in a different, but still wrong, position.

If I try with an even more minimal code, like the following, instead, everything goes fine:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        ax[row, col].text(0.5, 0.5, str((row, col)), color='blue', fontsize=18, ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any guess why? Thanks! :)

Comment: try `axs[row, col].text(0.5, 0.5, str((row, col)),color='blue', fontsize=18, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes`) as the default coordinates are data coordinates, but you need axes coordinates. In your more minimal example axes and data coordinates are the same by chance.

Comment: whats Deltas_list ?